# Absolute simplest example of an Functional Observable pattern in React

Tags: reactjs, components, observer-pattern

Can anyone provide a stupid-simple example of an observable in ReactJS?

Basically I want to communicate a message from one component to another.

Google searches have send me down rabbit holes with RxJs, Redux, Hooks, shared memory, Class-based components, and other involved topics.

Take the following structure for example:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 /\
D  E
```

I just need to send a true/false message from component D to C.

Is this inherently complex in React? tyvm, Keith :^)

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-usecontext

Comment: https://medium.com/@danfyfe/using-react-context-with-functional-components-153cbd9ba214

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFnfvhtrNbQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RxJS**

Redux-observable uses ReactiveX observables but I don't think it is the most commonly used method for React applications.

**React state**

React state (this.state or useState) only goes from parent to children so when D and C need state it has to be managed in a common ancestor which is A. This means that A needs to pass props to B that B doesn't need, only so B can pass it to C. This is called props drilling and is considered bad so not the best option.

**Redux and react-redux**

Redux store is an event store, you can dispatch actions (events) and reducers or middleware will act on these actions to update state (reducers) or cause side effects (usually done with middleware). The component(s) can use selectors to get data from state with `useSelector(selectorFunction)`, previously HOC `connect` was used but the hook is much simpler.

When an action is dispatched that causes state change then all the `selectorFunction` functions are called by react-redux and if their return value is different than last run it'll re render the component where `useSelector` was used.

Redux is a good candidate if you have to implement complex requirements as the CQRS/event store pattern makes it easy to separate actions (indicate what happened) from reducers (what to do when something happens) and you can query the store with selectors ([reselect](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) is commonly used).

**Context**

For applications that do not have complex requirements you may get away with using context, whenever you change a context the component that has `useContext` will re render. Below is a simple example.

```js
const BoolContext = React.createContext();
const BoolProvider = ({ children }) => {
  //set bool message to true
  const [bool, setBool] = React.useState(true);
  const toggle = React.useCallback(
    () => setBool((b) => !b),
    []
  );
  return (
    // set value of context to {bool, toggle}
    <BoolContext.Provider value={{ bool, toggle }}>
      {children}
    </BoolContext.Provider>
  );
};

const D = () => {
  const { bool, toggle } = React.useContext(BoolContext);
  return <button onClick={toggle}>D:{String(bool)}</button>;
};
const C = () => {
  const { bool, toggle } = React.useContext(BoolContext);
  return <button onClick={toggle}>C:{String(bool)}</button>;
};
//removed E as it does not do anything to demonstrate context
const B = () => ( <D /> )

const A = () => {
  return (
    <BoolProvider>
      <B />
      <C />
    </BoolProvider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<A />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Kindly explain ``{children}`` that is the only piece that is unclear. ty

Comment: @kmiklas In this case [children](https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891) (props.children) of `BoolProvider` is `<B /><C />`

Answer (score 1):

```
//Observer.js
class Observable {
  constructor() {
     this.observers = [];
  }

 subscribe(func) {
    this.observers.push(func);
 }

 unsubscribe(inputFunc) {
    this.observers.filter(func => func != inputFunc);
 }

 notify(data) {
    this.observers.forEach(func => func(data));
 }
}

export default new Observable();
```

---

```
function DisplayBlockA() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('Button A');

  useEffect(() => {
    observerPattren.subscribe((value) => setText(value));
    return () => {
      observerPattren.unsubscribe();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Button type="primary" block>{text}</Button>
  )
}
```

---

```
export default function App(){
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState();

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setInputText(event.target.value)
  }
  
  const onSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    observerPattren.notify(inputText);
  }, [inputText])

  return (
  <div>
        <Input value={inputText} onChange={onChange} />
        <Button type="primary" onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</Button>
        <DisplayBlockA />
        <DisplayBlockB />
  </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Read more https://www.patterns.dev/posts/observer-pattern

Comment: in reality we have used this pattern very rarely. redux also make use of observer pattern.