# Notify other component by raising a manual event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A have two files, with two functional components A and B, in the first component A, i have a `specialFunction` that gets called with `onClick`, what i want to do is raise an event in `specialFunction` when it's called, and then in component B add a `Listener` for the event in `specialFunction`.

Component A:

```js
function specialFunction(){
     //raise the event and send some data
}
```

Component B:

```js
//contains a listener that does some work when specialFunction is called, example:
(data) => {console.log("am called:",data)};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react: dispatch and listen to custom events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60927150/react-dispatch-and-listen-to-custom-events)

Comment: The duplicate is from 2020 so possibly things have changed, but for simplicities sake you should look into [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (or related libraries...)

Comment: Are you familiar with Context? If yes, you can use Observer patterns to create notifier and pass it through context.

Comment: see: [Absolute simplest example of an Functional Observable pattern in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63584365/absolute-simplest-example-of-an-functional-observable-pattern-in-react)

Comment: Use a shared service provided at root (singleton) and inject it in both components.... oh wait, you're using React :D

Comment: @pilchard The dispatch and listen did it for me :)

Comment: @guzmanoj Maybe it's time to switch :D, are you talking about Angular ?

Comment: @Marwane yessir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrius posted a really good answer, but my problem was that the two components, one of them is used as an API, and the other had a parent component, am a beginner so maybe there is a way to use them but i just didn't know how.

The solution that i used, (maybe not the best) but did the job was to dispatch a custom event in a `Promise` from the `specialFunction`:

```js
function specialFunction(){
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      console.log("am the promise");
      document.dispatchEvent(event);
      resolve();
    });
```

And add a `Listener` in the other component using a `useEffect` hook:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let handlePreview = null;
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      document.addEventListener(
        "previewImg",
        (handlePreview = (event) => {
          event.stopImmediatePropagation();
          //Stuff...
        })
      );
      return () =>
        window.removeEventListener("previewImg", handlePreview, false);
    });
  }, []);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Create notifier class using observer pattern**

```
class ChangeNotifier {
    subscribers = [];

    subscribe(callback) {
        this.subscribers.push(callback);
    }

    unsubscribe(callback) {
        const index = this.subscribers.indexOf(callback);
        if (index > -1) {
            this.subscribers.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    notifyAll(data) {
        this.subscribers.forEach(callback => callback(data));
    }
}
```

**2. ComponentA receives notifier as a prop and used to notify all subscribers**

```
const ComponentA = ({ notifier }) => {

    const triggerNotifier = () => {
        notifier.notifyAll('Some data that will subscribers receive');
    }

    return <div>{/** Some content */}</div>
}
```

**3. ComponentB receives notifier and subscribes to it to receive data sent by from ComponentB**

```
const ComponentB = ({ notifier }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const callbackFn = data => {/** Do whatever you want with received data */ }
        notifier.subscribe(callbackFn);

        return () => notifier.unsubscribe(callbackFn);
    }, [])

}
```

**4. App holds both component. Create instance of notifier there and pass as a props**

```
const App = () => {
    const dataNotifier = new ChangeNotifier();

    return <div>
        <ComponentA notifier={dataNotifier} />
        <ComponentB notifier={dataNotifier} />
    </div>
}
```

If you have components on different levels deeply nested and it is hard to pass notifier as a prop, please read about React Context which is very helpful when you want to avoid property drilling

[React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

**Here's implementation with context**

```
class ChangeNotifier {
    subscribers = [];

    subscribe(callback) {
        this.subscribers.push(callback);
        return this.unsubscribe.bind(this, callback);
    }

    unsubscribe(callback) {
        const index = this.subscribers.indexOf(callback);
        if (index > -1) {
            this.subscribers.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    notifyAll(data) {
        this.subscribers.forEach(callback => callback(data));
    }
}


const NotifierContext = React.createContext();




const ComponentA = () => {
    const { notifier } = useContext(NotifierContext);

    const triggerNotifier = () => {
        notifier.notifyAll('Some data that will subscribers receive');
    }

    return <div><button onClick={triggerNotifier}>Notify</button></div>
}


const ComponentB = () => {
    const { notifier } = useContext(NotifierContext);


    useEffect(() => {
        const callbackFn = data => { console.log(data) }
        notifier.subscribe(callbackFn);

        return () => notifier.unsubscribe(callbackFn);
    }, [notifier])

}
```

Now all components wrapped in NotifierContext.Provider (no matter how deep they are nested inside other components) will be able to use **useContext** hook to receive context value passed as **value** prop to NotifierContext.Provider

```
const App = () => {
    const dataNotifier = useMemo(() => new ChangeNotifier(), []);

    return <NotifierContext.Provider value={{ notifier: dataNotifier }}>
        <ComponentA />
        <ComponentB />
    </NotifierContext.Provider>

}

export default App;
```

Last but not least, I guess you can avoid context or properties drilling and just create instance of ChangeNotifier in some utility file and export it to use globally...